# how to transfer cmake env. vars into bash/automake script

Tags: linux, bash, cmake

in my cmake script I need to use dependency which is build/configured with custom bash script based on automake. I add this project something like that:

```
ExternalProject_Add(ICU
          PREFIX ${ICU_PREFIX}
          DOWNLOAD_DIR ${PRJ_DIR}/deps/icu-${ICU_VERSION}
          URL ${FindOrBuildICU_URL}
          URL_HASH ${ICU_URL_HASH}
          CONFIGURE_COMMAND
            sh ${ICU_PREFIX}/source/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
          BUILD_COMMAND
            make -j8
          INSTALL_COMMAND
          BUILD_BYPRODUCTS ${ICU_EP_LIBICUI18N})
```

The problem is that I have pretty complex env in cmake, with a plenty of variables, which configure compilation, compiler settings, compilation flow, etc.

Is there a way to somehow transfer this env. state to `bash/automake` without manually typing something like `CONFIGURE_COMMAND cmake -E env VAR1=${CMAKE_VAR1} VAR2 =${CMAKE_VAR2} ... sh ${ICU_PREFIX}/source/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>`?